# Track the Page Versions

Tags: mongodb, redis, ravendb, amazon-simpledb, document-database

Please guide me how to solve the following scenario using document-oriented database.

A page called 'Page1' (Version V1.0) can be a content page for documents 'Document1', 'Document2' and 'Document3'. If I edit the contents in 'Page1'(Version should changed from V1.0 to V1.1)  This change should reflect only on 'Document1' and 'Document2' but should not affect on 'Document3'.

Now documents 'Document1' and 'Document2' are refere the 'Page1'- Version V1.1. But document 'Document3' still refer the 'Page1' - Version V1.0.

Like this I need to keep track the changes/versions for all the pages.

To keep track of these changes NoSQL databases will be very usefule more than Relational databases.
So in document-oriented databases which one is solve this scenario?

Comment: You can do it wherever. As it stands, the question is too broad and not constructive. It depends on personal preferences...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Amazon S3 and keep your document over there. Amazon S3 supports versioning so whenever you download the doc, it always downloads the latest version. You can list all versions and restore any version which you would like to restore again. Amazon S3 will offload your task to keep records of version. So your cloud no sql database always point to current version.

Comment: Hi Ashish,<<So your cloud no sql database always point to current version.>>.  Is there possibility to point to old versions also?